# Specify the SELECT and use the built in mechanism for the WHERE in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible (**rails 3**) to specify the SELECT part of a rails query, and use the regular WHERE in order to write the conditions?

Something like:

```
Model.find_by_sql("SELECT blah blah FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON...").where([conditions, params])
```

Comment: Did you try this?  What happened?  Wouldn't that answer your question?

Comment: It was rhetorical- your question is way too broad as written.  When you tried it, it either worked or it didn't, and if it didn't, your question is really about why it didn't, so give us the information we need to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you are looking for:

```
Model.select('table_name1.field1, table_name2.field2')
     .joins('JOIN table_name2 ON (table_name2.table_name1_id = table_name1.id)')
     .where([conditions, params])
```